# Handlebars.js no output

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I am really struggling with Handlebars.js. The below example is the extent of my test html document.

I just cannot work out why the html variable is not writing the desired context content is not providing an output:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="entry">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <div class="body">
                {{body}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var source = $("#entry-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var context = {
            title: "My New Post",
            body: "This is my first post!"
        };
        var html = template(context);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Assigning the result of calling the template function to a variable won't have any visible effect on anything. You just end up with a variable called "html" with some text in it.

Comment: Ok, how would you go about writing this to the body? Using JQuery?

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = template(context);`